# Laravel namespace and use statement confusion

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I need to recreate an old Laravel 5.1 app in Code Igniter.

The app uses `Auth` in its controllers located under app/Http/Controllers:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
```

I am trying to find the source of where I can find this `Auth` code. The old app continues to call functions such as `Auth::user('admin')` and I have no idea where this code resides so I can actually see what it does.

Where would I access this file called `Auth`? I see under `Http/Controllers` there is an `Auth` folder, which is what I thought this referred to, but there is no `user` function that accepts a parameter in any of the classes in that folder.

In `config/` folder, I see a file called `auth.php` and there is the following piece of code:

```
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model'  => App\Admin::class,
    'table'  => 'guestuser'
],
```

But I fail to see how this links to anything, as I cannot find `App\Admin` either.

Comment: Laravel to CodeIgnitor? you are moving backwards ;-)

Comment: @lagbox Not helpful. But thanks for your insight ;-)

Comment: this is not a Laravel 5.1 project or you have some other package that is handling multi auth

Comment: @lagbox, it sure is Laravel 5.1, but you are right on the second part of your statement. There is a package called sarav/laravel-multiauth. It extends the original Guard class, and contains no user() function, so it inherits from the original Guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth` refers to the Auth Facade. Laravel uses facades as a way to easily grab services from the service container without needing to inject them. You can see a [list of the facades and the class they refer to in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades#facade-class-reference).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now have found the class AuthManager which in turns uses Manager and Guard, and neither of them has a user function that accepts a parameter. I am so confused. This function is setting some data that is used to do database queries with, and I need to see where it retrieves that data from.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh its the `Guard` that the call is on ... and correct it does not take a parameter ... the configuration code you are showing above is not from Laravel 5.1 but a newer version than that

Comment: @lagbox, thanks, but why does the call `Auth::user('admin')` then appear to have a parameter?

Comment: it doesn't in any guards that laravel comes with in any version .. .either someone is passing it and not realizing it does nothing, or you have some extra package handling multiauth potentially

Comment: Yes, Laravel uses OOP extensively so to understand Laravel, you need to understand OOP. Codeignighter also uses OOP (albeit poorly IMO), so you should probably brush up on your OOP fundamentals. Without seeing the code it's hard to know what is going on, but from what you did post I assume whoever wrote that code meant to do `Auth::guard('admin')->user();`, but never tested it to make sure it does what they thought.